# aiokafka ProducerClosed error while producing messages asynchronously

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

I am using aiokafka to produce messages asynchronously. I have an Api using django which is producing messages to kafka queue. It was working fine. Now When I have converted the same api to use aiohttp server then following error is coming:-

> aiokafka.errors.ProducerClosed: ProducerClosed

First message is getting produced successfully. Above error is coming on 2nd message production.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
producer = AIOKafkaProducer(
    loop=loop,
    bootstrap_servers="127.0.0.1:9092"
)
await producer.start()
response = await producer.send_and_wait(queue_name, msg)
await producer.stop()
```

There is no information regarding this error in aiokafka docs. Please help.

Edit:
I am shaing this producer among handers. If I leave the producer open, will it cause any issues? When the producer will be closed automaticaly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> aiokafka.errors.ProducerClosed: ProducerClosed

This error [occurs](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka/blob/9756b332eb650163819675fd327b2f0992564b27/aiokafka/producer/message_accumulator.py#L322) when a message is sent to a closed producer.

If you share producer among handlers, make sure that you don't close it after the first message is produced.

Edit: you can close it in [cleanup context](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#cleanup-context)

```py
async def kafka(app):
    await producer.start()
    yield
    await producer.stop()


app.cleanup_ctx.append(kafka)
```

Without it, all connections [will try to close](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka/blob/10bdd29d569f827605789d8c9910c32483b49346/aiokafka/conn.py#L166)

Comment: Then should I leave it open? When should I close it? And if it's open then will it cause any problems like memory leak etc

Comment: @ChandanKumar Yes, you should leave it open, if you want to share it. I updated the answer to show how to close it